# Which statistical test is suitable to compare order statistics of two independent samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, order-statistics, permutation-test

Say I want to compare two order statistics (say the 2nd largest value or min value) of two samples. Let's not make any distributional assumptions except that the variance is finite?

Is something like the Mann-Whitney U test adaptable here? A permutation test or bootstrap hypothesis test seem like it would be strange given that we only have two statistics (one of each sample) of each order from the empirical distributions.

The tests I have in mind are whether the statistics are equal or whether the statistics are from the same distribution.

Comment: I think this asks: If $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are both samples of size $n$ and we know only $(X_{(1)},Y_{(1)})$ or $(X_{(n-1)},Y_{(n-1)})$, can we conclude anything about whether the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ were drawn from the same distribution? If that is the question, the answer is clearly no.

Comment: This comes up in auction research.  I think An Introduction to the Structural Econometrics of Auction Data by Harry J. Paarsch and Han Hong would cover this, but don't have my copy handy to check.